# HttpServer with more than one responder

Tags: java, rpc, avro, httpserver

In my application (java) I need to support two types of RPCs: 
Administration RPC and User RPC. I am using avro to create these RPCs, currently I am opening two HttpServers one per RPC using code similar to the following:

```
Server serverAdmins = new HttpServer(new ReflectResponder(AdministrationRPC.class, arpcImpl), adminRpcPort);
Server serverUsers = new HttpServer(new ReflectResponder(UsersRPC.class, urpcImpl), usersRpcPort);
...
```

This works, but it look like a waste for me - I am looking for a way to use a single http server with two ports or two urls on the same port (any of these options is good for me), something like:

```
Server server = new new HttpServer(new ReflectResponder(AdministrationRPC.class, arpcImpl), adminRpcPort);
server.addResponder(new ReflectResponder(UsersRPC.class, urpcImpl), usersRpcPort);
...
```

the addResponder method does not exists of course, the only method that looks similar is the addConnector method - but even after thorough googling I couldn't find how to apply it to my needs..

Is there a way to start two avro responders on the same http server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by writing a simple class which allow for what I want, see code below.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.avro.ipc.HttpTransceiver;
import org.apache.avro.ipc.Responder;
import org.apache.avro.ipc.ResponderServlet;
import org.apache.avro.ipc.reflect.ReflectRequestor;
import org.apache.avro.ipc.reflect.ReflectResponder;
import org.mortbay.jetty.Server;
import org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context;
import org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

/**
 *
 * @author bennyl
 */
public class MultiResponderHttpServer {

    private final Context context;
    private final Server server;
    private final int port;

    public MultiResponderHttpServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        server = new Server(port);
        context = new Context(server, "/", Context.SESSIONS);
    }

    public void addResponder(String baseUri, Responder responder) throws IOException {
        ResponderServlet servlet = new ResponderServlet(responder);
        ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(servlet);
        context.addServlet(holder, baseUri);
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void close() throws Exception {
        server.stop();
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        server.start();
    }

    public void join() throws InterruptedException {
        server.join();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        MultiResponderHttpServer server = new MultiResponderHttpServer(8888);
        server.addResponder("/test_a/*", new ReflectResponder(TestProtocol.class,
                (TestProtocol) why -> "a received a message: '" + why + "'"));
        server.addResponder("/test_b/*", new ReflectResponder(TestProtocol.class,
                (TestProtocol) why -> "b received a message: '" + why + "'"));

        server.start();

        HttpTransceiver atrans = new HttpTransceiver(new URL("http://localhost:" + server.getPort() + "/test_a/"));
        HttpTransceiver btrans = new HttpTransceiver(new URL("http://localhost:" + server.getPort() + "/test_b/"));

        System.out.println(ReflectRequestor.getClient(TestProtocol.class, atrans).go("message to a"));
        System.out.println(ReflectRequestor.getClient(TestProtocol.class, btrans).go("message to b"));

        server.close();
        server.join();
    }

    public interface TestProtocol {

        String go(String why);
    }
}
```